# Authorization handler without requirement ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

So I Have a Authorization handler as such:

```
public class StationToIDMMatchHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;
        private readonly AftermarketDbContext _db;

        public StationToIDMMatchHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, AftermarketDbContext db)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _db = db;
        }


        public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
        {
            HttpContext httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext; // Access context here

            string StationUniqueId = httpContext.Request.Headers.Where(x => x.Key == " StationUniqueId").FirstOrDefault().Value;

            var listOfRoles = context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "groups").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

            string requiredIDMRole = _db.StationRole.Where(DbStationUniqueId => DbStationUniqueId.StationId == StationUniqueId).ToString();


            if (listOfRoles.Contains(requiredIDMRole))
            {
                context.Succeed();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
                return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't have any requirement other than the ones I already checked that I want to return. And  I can't use a `context.Succeed();`without a parameter.
How do I do this? Must I really create a empty class that implements IAuthorizationRequrement to send in? This does not seem like a good way to do it.

Comment: FYI : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationhandlercontext.succeed?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authorization-authorizationhandlercontext-succeed(microsoft-aspnetcore-authorization-iauthorizationrequirement) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationhandlercontext.pendingrequirements?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authorization-authorizationhandlercontext-pendingrequirements

Comment: Have a look at [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0).